# Dynamically calling constructor from IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

Consider the following:

```
function windowTest() { }

(function () {
    function test() { }

    var test1 = new test(); // Works fine.
    var test2 = new window["windowTest"](); // Works since windowsTest is declared globally.
    var test3 = new window["test"]();  // Fails since in an IIFE.

    // How can I create a testObj if I only have the string "test"?
})();
```

Basically, I want to create an object whose function was declared in an IIFE.

Comment: Re `test3`: Why do you need to access that function on the `window` object instead of using it directly?

Comment: why does new test() not work?

Comment: test() does indeed work, updated the comment.

Comment: @MikeC, I'm just looking for a syntax that would get "var test3 = new window["test"]()" to work.  Kind of like how "reflection" was used to invoke the object declared globally.  But I want to do it in an IIFE.

Comment: `test` is scoped to the IIFE--since it's not on `window`, no, there's no way to get that to work. You could use `eval`, but yuck. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I created my own framework on top of knockoutJS to very easily and dynamically create my huge view models recursively.  However, it relies on "new window['constructorName']" to create all of my objects.  The idiot that I am, I didn't think global scope would be an issue.  Not smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason

```
var test3 = new window["test"]();
```

fails is because `test` was not declared globally. If you want to access items declared directly within the IIFE, as you know, you can access them by name.

```
new test();
```

Another way is to store your function inside of some kind of object then access that object like you did with `window`. This is almost always the solution to these kinds of problems.

```js
(function() {
  var context = {
    test: function() {
      console.log('new test');
    }
  };
  
  var test = new context['test']();
})();
```

The last way uses [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). `eval` is almost always [a really bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) Really, it should be avoided unless you're abusing the language just for the sake of interest. But you *can* use it in this case.

```js
(function() {
  function test() {
    console.log('new test');
  }
  
  var test = eval('new test()');
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your functions to this:

```
function(){
 //your code using
 this.test("Hi");
 this["test"]("Hi");
}.call({
 //function declarations:
 test:window.alert,
});
```

Still an IIFE so it wont work in the global context :

```
this.test("Hi");//reference Error
```